# Access calculated number Field: modulo problem

Tags: ms-access, calculated-field, modulo

I have a problem with my expression in a Calculated field in an access [2007] table.
I need to find out if a number is odd or even but I can't get the Modulo function to work.

This doesn't work:
IIf( [No] Mod 2 = 0, [No] - 1, [No] + 1)

[
Just to check - the following expression works (eventhough nonsense):
IIf( [No] > 2, [No] - 1, [No] + 1)
]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works in queries, but not in calculated fields. Strange.
You can solve it like this instead:

```
IIf([Field1]/2=Round([Field1]/2), [Field1]-1, [Field1]+1)
```

Not Mod, but the same result